# cast LinkedHashMap to HashMap in groovy

Tags: java, collections, groovy, hashmap, linkedhashmap

How do I convert `LinkedHashMap` to `java.util.HashMap` in groovy?

When I create something like this in groovy, it automatically creates a `LinkedHashMap` even when I declare it like `HashMap h = ....` or `def HashMap h = ...`

I tried doing:

```
HashMap h = ["key1":["val1", "val2"], "key2":["val3"]]
```

and

```
def HashMap h = ["key1":["val1", "val2"], "key2":["val3"]]
```

`h.getClass().getName()` still comes back with `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Just curious, why do you care what implementation of `Map` it's creating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` is a subclass of `HashMap` so you can use it as a `HashMap`.

---

**Resources :**

- [javadoc - LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: I agree. I should not matter what implementation of a HashMap it uses.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer -- maps have something that looks a lot like a copy constructor:

```
Map m = ['foo' : 'bar', 'baz' : 'quux'];
HashMap h = new HashMap(m);
```

So, if you're wedded to the literal notation but you absolutely have to have a different implementation, this will do the job.

But the real question is, why do you care what the underlying implementation is?  You shouldn't even care that it's a HashMap.  The fact that it implements the Map interface should be sufficient for almost any purpose.

Comment: I came across the same issue, whereby I am trying to compare a Map in an assertEquals via `assertEquals("Checking Data Input Variable 5/9 - Define attr", ["male": 0, "female": 1], var5.define)` and the assertion fails because the actual type is `HashMap` whereas the expected type is `LinkedHashMap`. Maybe I'll write my own `assertMapEquals()` function that uses your suggestion...

Answer (score 2):

He probably got caught with the dreaded Groovy-Map-Gotcha, and was stumbling around in the wilderness of possibilities as I did for the entire afternoon.

Here's the deal:

When using variable string keys, you cannot access a map in property notation format (e.g. map.a.b.c), something unexpected in Groovy where everything is generally concise and wonderful ;--)

The workaround is to wrap variable keys in parens instead of quotes.

```
def(a,b,c) = ['foo','bar','baz']  
Map m = [(a):[(b):[(c):1]]]  
println m."$a"."$b"."$c" // 1  
println m.foo.bar.baz // also 1
```

Creating the map like so will bring great enjoyment to sadists worldwide:

```
Map m = ["$a":["$b":["$c":1]]]
```

Hope this saves another Groovy-ist from temporary insanity...

Answer (score 1):

```
 HashMap h = new HashMap() 
 h.getClass().getName();
```

works.  Using the [:] notation seems to tie it to LinkedHashMap.